# how to compare between linear regression (second-order) and Kalman filter?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, polynomials, kalman-filter

I'd like to compare between Kalman filter and linear regression after applying polynomial from the second order.

I'm not an expert with Kalman filter and I don't know how to implement the code for compersion. So, I am asking you to help.

I found this [link](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2348/what-is-the-relationship-between-a-kalman-filter-and-polynomial-regression) explaining the main differences.

How to compare between them?

your help would be appreciated.

Full code for linear regression.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None  # default='warn'
data = [5.269, 5.346, 5.375, 5.482, 5.519, 5.57, 5.593999999999999, 5.627000000000001, 5.724, 5.818, 5.792999999999999, 5.817, 5.8389999999999995, 5.882000000000001, 5.92, 6.025, 6.064, 6.111000000000001, 6.1160000000000005, 6.138, 6.247000000000001, 6.279, 6.332000000000001, 6.3389999999999995, 6.3420000000000005, 6.412999999999999, 6.442, 6.519, 6.596, 6.603, 6.627999999999999, 6.76, 6.837000000000001, 6.781000000000001, 6.8260000000000005, 6.849, 6.875, 6.982, 7.018, 7.042000000000001, 7.068, 7.091, 7.204, 7.228, 7.261, 7.3420000000000005, 7.414, 7.44, 7.516, 7.542000000000001, 7.627000000000001, 7.667000000000001, 7.821000000000001, 7.792999999999999, 7.756, 7.871, 8.006, 8.078, 7.916, 7.974, 8.074, 8.119, 8.228, 7.976, 8.045, 8.312999999999999, 8.335, 8.388, 8.437999999999999, 8.456, 8.227, 8.266, 8.277999999999999, 8.289, 8.299, 8.318, 8.332, 8.34, 8.349, 8.36, 8.363999999999999, 8.368, 8.282, 8.283999999999999]

time = range(1,85,1)
x=int(0.7*len(data))
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(*[time, data])))
df.columns = ['time', 'data']
# print df
x=int(0.7*len(df))
train = df[:x]
valid = df[x:]
models = []
names = []
tr_x_ax = []
va_x_ax = []
pr_x_ax = []
tr_y_ax = []
va_y_ax = []
pr_y_ax = []
time_model = []
models.append(('LR', LinearRegression()))

for name, model in models:
    x_train=df.iloc[:, 0][:x].values
    y_train=df.iloc[:, 1][:x].values
    x_valid=df.iloc[:, 0][x:].values
    y_valid=df.iloc[:, 1][x:].values

    model = LinearRegression()
    poly = PolynomialFeatures(2)
    x_train= x_train.reshape(-1, 1)
    y_train= y_train.reshape(-1, 1)
    x_valid = x_valid.reshape(-1, 1)
    y_valid = y_valid.reshape(-1, 1)
    # model.fit(x_train,y_train)
    x_train = poly.fit_transform(x_train)
    x_valid = poly.fit_transform(x_valid)
    model.fit(x_train,y_train.ravel())
    # score = model.score(x_train,y_train.ravel())
    # print 'score', score
    preds = model.predict(x_valid)
    tr_x_ax.extend(train['data'])
    va_x_ax.extend(valid['data'])
    pr_x_ax.extend(preds)

    valid['Predictions'] = preds
    valid.index = df[x:].index
    train.index = df[:x].index
    plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
    # plt.plot(train['data'],label='data')
    # plt.plot(valid[['Close', 'Predictions']])
    x = valid['data']
    # print x
    # plt.plot(valid['data'],label='validation')
    plt.plot(valid['Predictions'],label='Predictions ',color='orange')



y =range(0,58)
y1 =range(58,84)

pr_x_ax = list([float(i) for i in pr_x_ax])
va_x_ax = list([float(i) for i in va_x_ax])
tr_x_ax = list([float(i) for i in tr_x_ax])
plt.plot(y,tr_x_ax,  label='train' , color='red',  linewidth=2)

plt.xlabel("time")
plt.ylabel("data")
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The output:
[image]

Comment: The linear regression gives you the MSE linear model from all the training data.  The KF is learning as it goes.  Properly formulated it's also giving you the MSE linear model given the training data it's seen so far.  If you have all the training data upfront, the regression is the better approach.

Comment: @KeithBrodie Thanks.